# Reduce the use of for loop when checking strings in lists in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I would like to find a way or method to reduce the use of for loop. I tried to check itertools documentation but cant find any relevant ones. I am currently using at least 4-5 times for loop and this will make it loop toooooooo deeeep and too time consuming when having big dataset.

Is there anyway to reduce the use of for loop? My main goal is to learn about reducing the use of for loop and not about the output.

Here is my code:

```
aa = [[[] for i in range(10)] for i in range(10)]


diction = {"m":"something", "k":"something", "a":"something"}
a = [["m", "baba", "black", "no", "sheep"], ["k", "kong", "came", "out"]]

for opt in diction.keys():
    for i, ix in enumerate(a):
        for ii, iix in enumerate(ix):
            for iixx in iix:
                print(iixx)
                if opt == iixx:
                    aa[i][ii].append(
                            [iixx])
```

Goal of questions:

Reduce from 4-5 times for loop to 1-2 if possible or 1-3.

Comment: What is your expected output?  Even if you are not mainly concerned with the output, it's still useful to provide it.  That way answers can be verified.

Comment: I see. Let's say the output should be the similar as the current output from the current code? Will this be enough? Actually, I wrote this code as dummy for me to understand and learn about the use of for loop and also since I am concern about looping way too deep, thats why I thought of reducing the loop if possible. Somehow, when I have too many files, I tend to use for loop too many times.

Comment: Ok fair enough, and creating dummies is a great way to learn. However they should have a goal. If the goal is to get the same result by using many nested loops... that's not really a goal I'd say.

Comment: Btw, I build the code this way to loop until each characters because this is the max loop that I could do for a sentence. My main intention is to see how many for loops could be reduce and the output is to have the character similar to the diction.keys() and then append it into the list.

Comment: I see. Yea, true. I agree with that. I would like to first apologize because I really didnt give any thoughts about the output since I was only thinking about learning the way to reduce it. Please hold on, let me redefine my output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an index dict to keep track of the two indices of each character, and then use set intersection to find matching characters. The key is to take advantage of the `O(1)` average lookup time for dicts and linear average lookup time for set intersections:

```
aa = [[[] for i in range(10)] for i in range(10)]
index = {}
for i, l in enumerate(a):
    for j, s in enumerate(l):
        for c in s:
            index.setdefault(c, []).append((i, j))
for c in diction.keys() & index.keys():
    for i, j in index[c]:
        aa[i][j].append([c])
```

Comment: wow, thank you so much sir. I learnt something. Alright, I will do that.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Do mark the answer you find the most helpful as accepted once you've reviewed all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the innermost loop, you can check if `opt in iix`, which is slightly cleaner.

You could also do the whole thing in a list comprehension, which is faster:

`aa = [[[opt for opt in diction if opt in iix] for iix in ix] for ix in a]`.

However, none of this will ultimately result in an asymptotic speedup for your problem; that complexity is ultimately dictated by what you're trying to do. If you need to check every combination of a set of items, that will take combinatorial time no matter what you do.

*edit: exclusively checking containment will give a different answer if the word contains more than one instance of a given key*

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I see, I have also consider about list comprehensions and its like you mentioned, it won't really help in reducing the time but to make it even more harder to understand. I understand that now and I will just learn some other codes and thank you for the answer.